# The timeout configured in the configuration string is not being used

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have this configuration (connection) string `***.redis.cache.windows.net:,password=***,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=15000` and it looks like the `connectTimeout` is not being used from this error that I got:

```
Timeout awaiting response (outbound=3830KiB, inbound=0KiB, 5172ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms)
```

This is how I initialize my connection:

```
        _lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {                
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(my_connection_string);
        });
```

I am using StackExchange.Redis v2.1.30 with .Net Core 2.1 and our project is deployed on Azure running version 4.0.14. Can somebody tell what I missed?

Answer (score 1):

It was an oversight on my part! I did not look at the error message carefully. The timeout was not about connecting but about waiting for the response. So the `connectTimeout` is not the correct config item to look into but the `synctimeout`. I just had to replace connectTimeout with synctimeout and the issue was resolved.